# Trying to print data from a db in a html tabel, but it did not print it right

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working whit a simple site on a PHP server that print a series of data in a table but when i open it, instead of printing the data it prints **{$row['tempLog']}** etc. Where is the problem :\

connect.php

```
<?php

function Connection(){


    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "EasyMon", "test");

    if ($connection->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $connection->connect_errno . ") " . $connection->connect_error;
    }
    echo $connection->host_info . "\n";

    return $connection;
    }
?>
```

Here the index.php site:

```
    <?php

    include("connect.php");     

    $link=Connection();

    $result=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `Tabella1` ORDER BY `tempLog`");

?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dati</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Potenziometro e sensore</h1>

        <table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;Timestamp&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Temperature&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;Moisture&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            if($result!==FALSE){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
                    echo ("<tr><td>{$row['tempLog']}</td><td>{$row['potenza']}</td><td>{$row['sensore']}</td></tr>");
                }
                mysqli_free_result($result);
                mysqli_close($link);
            }
        ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First silly question: is your file saved as .php? Second silly question: is your file hosted on a PHP web server?

Comment: You mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` (`mysql_fetch_array($result`)

Comment: ..and wrong order of arguments given in `mysqli_query()`, and we don't know what `new Connection()` does, nor whats inside connect.php.

Comment: Converting `mysql_` to `mysqli_` is not as simple as adding an `i` to the function calls

Comment: [Read the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) Its written in many languages

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is just a bad attempt to convert `mysql_` calls to `mysqli_` calls

Comment: Lol i miswrite everithing, i'm gonna edit

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: My server (virtual machine) use PHP 5.6.30 so it shuld still work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the need to upgrade still applies, because it wont when your host want to upgrade you to PHP7

Comment: I've just noticed that MySQLi commands are really similar to MySQL : |

Comment: But my actual problem now is that the site doesn't print the data, it just print the table labels and i don't know why

Comment: just test it without using string interpolation, in case that's the problem, e.g. `echo ("<tr><td>{".$row['tempLog']."}</td>` etc. Obviously we don't know whether you've got the field names right either - bear in mind that they're case-sensitive, for instance.

Comment: Field names are right, i think i can just use **pritnf**, something like **printf("<tr><td> &nbsp;%s </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td><td> &nbsp;%s&nbsp; </td></tr>",$row["tempLog"], $row["potenza"], $row["sensore"]);** to incapsulate thi prints in the table